# How to determine which tables use a sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have a sequence in a SQL Server 2012 database that appears in sys.sequences. How do I determine which tables use this sequence? I do not have sufficient permissions to view the definition of this system view so can't dig around for clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you a list of constraints and their definitions which contain `NEXT VALUE FOR`, which implies they are a sequence. Then you can see the sequence name in the definition.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) TABLE_NAME,
       c.name COLUMN_NAME,
       dc.name CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       dc.definition [DEFINITION]
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc
        ON c.default_object_id = dc.object_id
WHERE dc.definition LIKE '%NEXT VALUE FOR%'
```

You could reverse this to search by sequence name.

However, if you do not have access to `sys.sequences`, it's unlikely you'll have any access to tables above.

I'd suggest getting an admin to put the refined code into a stored proc that has permissions, so you can access it without getting access to the underlying tables.

I can't seem to find a direct link between a sequence and a constraint or column, the definition is the only mention of it I can find. I suppose it's not a traditional relationship, just a block of code the constraint runs.

Comment: Thank you Ollie - that worked. Interestingly, the sequences that I was after were not actually used in any tables. I do have access to the tables BTW, just didn;t have access to look under the hood of sys.sequences to see if there were any FK relationships e.g. to sys.columns to give me a clue

Comment: You may want to also look at sys.sql_modules as it could be referenced inside a stored procredure.  But it could be utilized in an ad-hoc piece of code, or through an SSIS package, or lots of places.

Answer (score 7):

A quick test shows that sequence references are tracked via [sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql) in SQL Server 2014 SP2. I don't have access to SQL Server 2012, but you can use the following query to (have an admin) confirm whether they're tracked in 2012 as well. If so, this might provide a slightly more rigorous way to find the references you are looking for.

```
-- Find all objects that reference each sequence on the database
SELECT s.object_id AS sequence_object_id,
    s.name AS sequence_name,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.parent_object_id) + '.'
        + OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id) AS table_name,
    r.*
FROM sys.sequences s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id) + '.' + s.name,
    'OBJECT'
) r
JOIN sys.objects o
    ON o.object_id = r.referencing_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and found the solution provided by @Geoff-Patterson. I found the solution a bit slow and filtering it was almost as slow as running the entire statement.

This statement should give the same result, but in a much faster way.

```
SELECT 
s.object_id AS sequence_object_id,
s.name AS sequence_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(oParent.schema_id) +'.'+ oParent.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS referencing_schema_name,
o.name AS referencing_entity_name,
dep.referencing_id,
dep.referencing_class,
dep.referencing_class_desc,
dep.is_caller_dependent

FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS dep on dep.referencing_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.sequences AS s ON dep.referenced_id = s.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS oParent ON o.parent_object_id = oParent.object_id
--WHERE oParent.name = 'TableName'
```